# Reference to previous row in the same row Power BI

Tags: excel, database, datatable, powerbi

Is it possible to make formula like this in power bi

*example 1:*

`if(table[column1]=1,table[column1],table[column1 -1]`

I know there is a way to make new column with index and use formula like this

*example 2:*

`column2=LOOKUPVALUE(table[column1],table[Index],table[Index]-1)`

But I need to make reference to previous row and when I use

*example 3:*

`("if(table[column1]=1,table[column1],table[column2]")`

I see the error "A circular Dependency was detected".

In excel there is no problem to make this reference.

Comment: What's issue are you having with example 2?

Comment: Because I cant make a reference back to column1

Comment: If I google "DAX Prior Row" there's a whole bunch of youtube explaining how.

Comment: Not exactly, all the things that I can find is method that I wrote in example 2 or with earlier function. All of this ways works but still I cant make a reference back to my main column https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-Reference-previous-row-in-same-column/m-p/639422 I found this one but here answer is that is impossible.

Comment: You are creating a new column right?

Comment: My goal is to not create but I can. I can reference to previous row in next column without problem. The problem begin when I am trying make reference to this new column with my old one

Comment: You need to understand that there is no "Order of rows" concept in Power BI, this is because it is more DB like. If you want a reference to an earlier row, you need to be able to identify the row. You can doe this by creating an index on the table. More likely you need to reference based on time, also this is possible because you can use date field also te get "earlier" or "Later" rows. My advice: you are not working in a spreadsheet application but in a DB, think as such.